# Creating preview thumbnails on progress bar hover for YouTube chromeless iFrame player

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I'm creating a chromeless YouTube player, using the iframe API, and everything is working and all good, except I can't figure out how I should go about getting those thumbnail 'previews' to show up. I'm talking about when you hover over the progress bar in a normal YouTube video, you see thumbnails that represent each given second. That functionality comes 'for free' if you use an embedded player, but I'm not sure how I can re-create it with chromeless.

There seems to be nothing in the YouTube API that gives you access to thumbnails at a given point in time.

Is there any way to mimic this functionality without getting out of hand hacky?

BTW, the reason I'm using chromeless is that we need a very specific design to incorporate the video functionality I'm building into the existing site.

I've looked around a lot on Google and SO, and have come up empty so far. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Probably nothing in the API - I have looked too.  But this might help https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-thumbnails

Comment: Have the same question, got any success?

Comment: unfortunately no. We ended up just giving up on that feature.

Comment: Hi is this api available now?